# Say "Her face is triangle" is wrong or right?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Ok, if I say "**Her face is triangle***".

I believe that the sentence is wrong logically because "**triangle**" is never an adjective but a noun. The face is a face and thus can not be a shape, right?

I think it is ok to say "**Her face shape is a triangle***" because "*triangle is a shape*". A face shape is a shape, so that sentence is **OK**.

But if we say "**Her face is square***", then that is OK because "**square**" is an adjective with the meaning "*having a square shape*".

I don't understand why we have "**Square**" (noun) & "**Square**" (adj), but "**Triangle**" (noun) but no "**Triangle**" (adj).

However, Google returns with 440 results for "**Her face is triangle**".

And saying "**Her face is  triangular**" is OK right?

I ask this question because I am not sure whether I am correct.

Comment: Are we a bit obsessed with faces today? (http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/75975/is-it-ok-to-say-the-actor-tom-cruises-face-shape-is-square)

Comment: I think this is more idiomatic: *She has a triangle-shaped face*. By the same token, these should be acceptable, too: *Her face is triangle-shaped. Her face is triangular-shaped*.

Comment: RE: _I believe that the sentence is wrong logically because "triangle" is never an adjective but a noun._ I agree that _triangular_ would be a better choice. That said, be careful about using words like _never_ when it comes to English. Moreover, be careful about Google hit counts, too. If you page through those 400+ results, you'll find it's more like 20 than 400 – and, furthermore, most of those are saying "Her face is triangle-**shaped**", which is quite different from "Her face is triangle." And one hit has VERY poor English: _My familliy is 5 people. At first, I discribe about my mother._

Comment: @DamkerngT.  - "Triangular-shaped" sounds odd, because "triangular" is already describing a shape.  Just "Her face is triangular" sounds a little more fluent.

Comment: @stangdon Very true indeed. However, I can't argue with real examples I found in Google Books. :( (:-))

Comment: As a note: you can't say "her face shape is triangle", it would have to be "her face shape is **a** triangle".

Comment: You could say *Her face is a triangle*. As a singular count noun, *triangle* normally needs a determiner before it.

Comment: @NES, a face can not be a triangle. A face is a face & a triangle is a shape. You got a logical problem

Comment: I guess, @Tom, you've never heard of metaphorical language?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The adjective form of various shapes ending in "angle" is usually *shapename*-ular.

So, for example.

> **circle** -> ***circular*** 
>   **rectangle** -> ***rectangular*** 
>   **triangle** -> ***triangular***

Square is an exception. The adjective form of square is just square.

The correct form of what you're trying to say is

> Her face is **triangular**.

Though I don't think someone would take kindly to that comment, so I would keep that comment in your exercise books only.

Answer (score 6):

This is a case in English where idiomatic syntax prevails over rules of grammar in practical usage.

Most native speakers would say one of the following (most common at the top):

**Triangles**

- Her face is shaped like a triangle.
- Her face is triangular.
- Her face is triangularly shaped.
- Her face is shaped triangularly.
- Her face is shaped triangular. (This one is incorrect grammar because triangular is an adjective, not an adverb. But it is still used; albeit incorrectly.)

**Squares**

- Her face is shaped like a square.
- Her face is squarely shaped.
- Her face is square-shaped.
- Her face is shaped squarely.

*Source: Native speaker*

Comment: As another native speaker, "Her face is shaped like a triangle" sounds more like an insult or a joke. "Her face is triangular" or "She has a triangular face" would seem more polite.

Comment: I would sooner say "triangle-shaped" than "triangularly-shaped". Adding -ly to "[shape]ular" to form an adverb would likely be understood, but in my experience is only found in practice when someone speaking is fumbling with their words.

Answer (score 1):

You've gotten an answer to the part about "Her face is triangle/ular", so let me address another of your sentences:

> *Her face shape is triangle.

This sentence is also incorrect.  Native speakers would never say *her face shape*.  We would instead say *the shape of her face*.  And we would still use *triangular* instead of *triangle* with this subject phrase.

(This is Just One Of Those Things.  I cannot think of an explanation.)

Answer (score 0):

Seconding *triangular* - "square" is not a very important exception because it is just a special case of *rectangular*.

So the rule to add -ular certainly holds.

See also *polygonal*.